# Differential Equations Validating Solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

### Fixed Post

### Sorry about that I mixed up today's lecture of IVP, with the previous one.

$\mathbf{Question}$ Verify that the indicated family of functions is a solution of given differential equation.
$$\frac{dP}{dt}=P(1-P); \ \ \ \ P=\frac{c_1 e^t}{1+c_1e^t}$$

For this question all I would do is substitute in the for P the equation.

### Following Procedure

\begin{align}
\frac{(1+c_1 e^t)c_1 e^t - c_1^2 e^{2t}}{(1+c_1e^t)^2} &= \frac{c_1e^t}{1+c_1e^t} - \frac{c_1^2e^{2t}}{(1+c_1e^t)^2} \\
\frac{c_1e^t}{(1+c_1e^t)^2} &= \frac{c_1e^t}{(1+c_1e^t)^2}\\
\end{align}
Since both sides are equivalent would that mean that the given solution is valid right? To Ian I also realized it said assume a valid I, interval of definition.

Comment: You should be a bit careful about what exactly the question is asking. Typically you would ask for the interval of definition of the solution of a particular IVP, which in this case would be $dP/dt=P(1-P),P(t_0)=P_0$. You can then figure out how $c_1$ depends on $(t_0,P_0)$. Then either a particular IVP will have a singularity, or else the $c$'s that you are worried about are simply not possible choices for solutions of an IVP.

Comment: (By the way, note that that expression is undefined on a whole curve in the $(c_1,t)$ plane, namely the curve $c_1=-e^{-t}$.)

Comment: @Ian My bad I mixed it up with today's lecture, the original problem says to indicate whether the indicated expression is an appropriate interval of I of definition for each solution. I am going to make edits.

Comment: @Ian Fixed the problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: @amd I clarified my question.

Comment: I still don’t see a question there. Are you asking for someone to verify your work?

Comment: @amd Yes basically, because I did the question, and would like to know if I'm right.